# Finding the number of lines(Height) to make a UITextfield & Cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

As I get strings of text down from my database, I need to know how big to make the UITextField and how big to make the Cell of the table that contains the UITextfield.

Are there any clever methods that can determine this? Since it will of course depend on the textfield width and the font used.

Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSString` has a method `sizeWithFont:contrainedToSize:` that will give you to the size of a string with a particular font:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.f];
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, 1000.f);

CGSize stringSize = [myString sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:size];
```